# AWS API Gateway - Set CORS for specific domains and stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I am trying to achieve a really basic thing on AWS API Gateway: Set cors headers for specific domains. If I use any web server like Nginx, Apache, I can easily set CORS header based on the domain, for example:

If the request cames from domainA or domainB I will set CORS Headers, otherwise not.

AWS API gateway only allow setting one **access-control-allow-origin**.

But my API will be accessed by more than one domain, so CORS header should be set dynamically based on the HTTP host request.

Is any way to achieve that without using any external code as lambda functions, etc?

My CORS Headers will also depend on the stage. Different stages will have different CORS Headers.

Anyone know if that's is possible to do using API gateway?

Comment: I believe CORS spec itself does not allow multiple domains. Only way out is use a lambda function.

Comment: Hello Amik! Exactly, I know that. Using servers such as Nginx, apache, we can write a custom function to check the origin domain and then set the CORS if the origin match our custom domain (Indeed we can not add multiple domains on Cors on http header). I was just wondering if that is possible to do this trick without calling a lambda function, but it sounds not possible. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628640/aws-api-gateway-cors-access-control-allow-origin-multiple-entries 
Seems like it is not possible without lambda. 
I will just put it here in the case someone else reach this question